# FadeIn with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to write a function so that when you hover over a hotspot the content of X div changes depending on what hotspot you're on.

I've been reading up on jQuery's fadeIn function only im unsure how I'd go about implementing it?

I've tried the below with no luck...

```
$(".texas").hover(
        function () {
            $(".description").fadeIn('slow').html("Texas");
        } 
    );
```

And below is my original code...

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".uk").hover(
        function () {
            $(".description").html("Test Blah");
        } 
    );
    $(".singapore").hover(
        function () {
            $(".description").html("singapore");
        } 
    );
    $(".texas").hover(
        function () {
            $(".description").html("Texas");
        } 
    );
});
```

---

```
<div class="wrap">
        <div class="description">
            <span class="country">Singapore</span>
            <p>Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis.</p><p>Debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. </p>
        </div>
         <div class="map">
            <a href="#" class="circle uk">Manchester</a>
            <a href="#" class="circle singapore">Singapore</a>
            <a href="#" class="circle texas">Texas</a>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Set the `.html` first and then use `fadein()`.

Comment: Need to see css and html.. try putting it on www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Still waiting for your HTML code, this is only your JS code.

Comment: @dmackerman I've tried $(".texas").hover(
   function () {
$(".description").html("Texas").fadeIn('slow');   } 
  ); with no luck...

Comment: Someone updated at the same time that @Liam did and overwrote his HTML.  I have rolled it back to his last update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this gets you the closest to what you are trying to achieve.

http://jsfiddle.net/fXTbf/

You don't want the fade effect to occur when you mouse over an already shown element. Next, you can bind to circle class as opposed to individual location classes.

```
$('.circle').bind('mouseover', 
    function () { 
        //if element is already active don't fade it in
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) { return; }

        //remove active class from old and add to new
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');     

        //fade out text, change it, and then fade in new value  
        $('.description span').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).html($('.active').html()).fadeIn('slow');
        });

    }
);
```

Comment: This works brilliantly, the only thing is that it only changes my header, I need it to change all the text within the relevant country....<span class='country'>Texas</span><p>Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis.</p><p>Debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. </p>

Comment: As you provided no feedback on what your html structure is for the other descriptions I invented my own. You now have two good answers that satisfy your original question. If you want to continue adding specifications I would ask them in a new question - http://jsfiddle.net/fXTbf/1/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what your HTML look like but I believe the below should work for you:

```
$(".texas").hover(function(){
   $(".desc").html("texas").fadeIn();
});
```

You can view the fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gcArd/

**UPDATE:**

Based on the HTML you posed this updated version should work for you:

```
$(".circle").mouseover(function(){
    var repText = $(this).text();
    $(".description").fadeOut(function(){
        $(".description").text(repText).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gcArd/2/

Comment: Is there a reason why it fades in and out multiple times instead of once?

Comment: Yeah, I fixed that.  Look at the latest version

Comment: Thanks @abe, my only concern then is it uses (this) text when I need it to use markup, ie <h6>Test</h6> <p>dsfsdg</p>

Comment: Ahh, you can swap out `text` for `html` in the example

Comment: But there needs to be 3 different text's, where would I put them? sorry im not very good with jquery

Comment: If you update your HTML with what you are talking about I can try and provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need a div or some container for each of the possible contents of .description. In that way, you could do this:

```
$(".texas").hover(
        function () {
            $(".ukDescription").fadeOut();
            $(".singaporeDescription").fadeOut();
            $(".texasDescription").fadeIn('slow');            
        } 
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based on Abe Miesser's answer. I thinks it's actually a lot less sluggy, visually speaking.

```
$(".circle").hover(function(){
   var self = $(this);
   if($(".description").text() != self.text()) {
       $(".description").fadeOut(function(){
           $(this).text(self.text()).fadeIn(); 
       })
   }
}, function(){
    $(".description").fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).text('');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y6Dp4/